# Error: "Module '"react-native"' has no exported member 'WebView'.ts(2305)"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

[image]

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {WebView} from 'react-native';

class MyWeb extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <WebView
        source={{
          uri: 'https://github.com/facebook/react-native',
        }}
        style={{marginTop: 20}}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`import Webview from 'react-native'` is deprecated. You can install WebView for `npm i react-native-webview`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';

class MyWeb extends Component {
  render() {
    return <WebView source={{ uri: 'https://reactnative.dev/' }} />;
  }
}
```